# JS Regex Help to match URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to match only urls C and D.

Given I have these sites:

```
a.  http://www.website.com/our-resources/news/?p=1
b.  http://www.website.com/example/voice-of-the-customer/news/?p=12
c.  http://www.website.com/our-resources/news/?p=123
d.  http://www.website.com/example/?p=4321
e.  http://www.website.com/example/products/touchchat/news/?p=12345
```

I was using `.*\?((.*=.*)(&?[0-9]{3,4}))` on [www.regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com) and it's matching c, d and e.

Comment: What is the criterion based on which you want to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/[^?]*\?.*=\d{3,4}(?:&|$)/
```

This will only match a URL with query parameter with 3 or 4 digits only (c & d test cases in your question).

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sX8fB3/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
.*\?((.*=)([0-9]{3,4}))
```

It was caused by the second `.*` in `.*=.*`